# IndexError: list index out of range when webscraping with Python

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, index-error

I am trying to figure out some webscraping and looking for a lot of tutorials in this topic.

However I've got to an issue where I manage to get satisfying results with the webscraping if I print it out once, however when I want to do more scraping I get IndexError: list index out of range.

What I want the program to do is webscrape the total amount of players on multiple servers and then print it out.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def server_status(port):
    # Get api together with port of the server
    # There are total 8 game servers with port ranging from 28900 - 28908
    URL = ("https://cod.pm/server/178.63.17.172/" + port)

    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

    # Find total players of the server
    x = soup.find_all(class_="col-auto")
    result = x[3].text

    return result



print(server_status("28901"))
print(server_status("28902"))
```

The error message I get in terminal is

```
app.py", line 14, in server_status
    result = x[3].text
             ~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I only print out port 28901 or only 28902 it works.

If I print 28901 and 28902 it gives me this error IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Of course you should start by inspecting the result of your find_all method. It clearly doesn't have a fourth item in the list. Are you sure you should have four or more found items?

Comment: Actually based on those last two sentences, this sounds a lot like a rate limiting issue.  The website doesn't want to be spammed, so when you call it many times in a short period, it starts denying your requests.

Comment: I think it could the what you say John, that it don't want to be spammed. 

If i add a time.sleep(3) between the prints it does print it out the way i want it.

Comment: I also see now on the site where i running it from has this it it's documentation:

"The site API is ratelimited to 1 request per second."

This think this is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

`print(len(x))` after you use find_all on soup object. Its length should be >= 4 in this case. alternatively, you can write soup object to a file and check the elements you can collect.

`with open('soup.txt', 'w') as f: f.write(soup)`

Comment: When i do print(len(x)) i get result 6.